# Interception of AJAX interaction of UIWebView and WebServer

Tags: ios, ajax, uiwebview, proxy, webkit

i'm trying to make a web browser with custom encryption for iOS.

For this i want to make a local proxy, which will implement crypt/encrypt logic of data, and interact with remote server.
And i want UIWebView to work with this proxy, like with web server.

The problem is ajax, where is a place to intercept UIWebView sending and receiving ajax requests and responses? How is it better to work with local proxy and xmlhttprequests?

Answer (score 0):

I had done the similar thing before.  Here are the steps:

1. Present user with a view that will allow them to enter their username and password.
2. Create an NSURL object with the URL you want to connect to.
3. Create an NSURLRequest object using the NSURL object you just created.
4. Create an NSURLConnection object using the NSURLRequest object you just created and set the delegate to be self.
5. Add connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge: to detect the challenge from the Web server.

Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of NSURLConnection  Class 
Hope this help!